# How to convert between timezones with win32 API?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I have date strings such as *2009-02-28 15:40:05 AEDST* and want to convert it into SYSTEMTIME structure. So far I have:

```
SYSTEMTIME st;
FILETIME ft;
SecureZeroMemory(&st, sizeof(st));
sscanf_s(contents, "%u-%u-%u %u:%u:%u",
    &st.wYear,
    &st.wMonth,
    &st.wDay,
    &st.wHour,
    &st.wMinute,
    &st.wSecond);
// Timezone correction
SystemTimeToFileTime(&st,  &ft);
LocalFileTimeToFileTime(&ft, &ft);
FileTimeToSystemTime(&ft, &st);
```

However my local timezone is not AEDST. So I need to be able to specify the timezone when converting to UTC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at this:

https://web.archive.org/web/20140205072348/http://weseetips.com:80/2008/05/28/how-to-convert-local-system-time-to-utc-or-gmt/

```
 // Get the local system time.
 SYSTEMTIME LocalTime = { 0 };
 GetSystemTime( &LocalTime );

 // Get the timezone info.
 TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION TimeZoneInfo;
 GetTimeZoneInformation( &TimeZoneInfo );

 // Convert local time to UTC.
 SYSTEMTIME GmtTime = { 0 };
 TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime( &TimeZoneInfo,
                                  &LocalTime,
                                  &GmtTime );

 // GMT = LocalTime + TimeZoneInfo.Bias
 // TimeZoneInfo.Bias is the difference between local time
 // and GMT in minutes. 

 // Local time expressed in terms of GMT bias.
 float TimeZoneDifference = -( float(TimeZoneInfo.Bias) / 60 );
 CString csLocalTimeInGmt;
 csLocalTimeInGmt.Format( _T("%ld:%ld:%ld + %2.1f Hrs"),
                          GmtTime.wHour,
                          GmtTime.wMinute,
                          GmtTime.wSecond,
                          TimeZoneDifference );
```

**Question: How do you get the TIME_TIMEZONE_INFORMATION for a specific timezone?**

Well unfortunately you cannot do that with the win32 API. Refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725481(VS.85).aspx) and [How do I get a specific TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION struct in Win32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466071/how-do-i-get-a-specific-timezoneinformation-struct-in-win32)

You will either need to create an empty variable and fill it in manually, or use the standard C time library.

Comment: Well unfortunately you cannot do that with the win32 API... see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725481(VS.85).aspx

You will either need to create an empty variable and fill it in manually, or use the standard C time library.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466071/how-do-i-get-a-specific-timezoneinformation-struct-in-win32

Comment: this also requires XP or greater.  TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime  does not work on Win2k

Comment: This answer is wrong. GetSystemTime() gets the UTC time, not the local time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [`TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725485(VS.85).aspx) Win32 API?

Comment: Thanks for that, but how do I retrieve the TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION for a different timezone (ie. AEDST)?