# How to get UTC time offset in c++ with windows os

Tags: c++, utc, timezone-offset

My question is pretty simple. How can I get the UTC offset for Philippines which is +8 and for Japan which is +9, and convert that to integer.

Any suggestions is a great help. Thank you.

**UPDATE**

For further explanation, I have a c++ desktop application, and I need to automatically detect its timezone wherever the application is used. Like if the application will be used in Japan, the timezone offset for japan will be used. Is that possible?

Comment: Please note you can't just convert hours offset to integer because there are few countries with fractional UTC offsets (like UTC+6:30)

Comment: Its okay. Because for now I'm working on an application that will be used in Philippines and Japan.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36630728/1132334, https://stackoverflow.com/a/597562/1132334, especially Winapi [retrieve the current time zone info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724421(v=vs.85).aspx), tried any of that? [Legislations change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_the_Philippines), so it is not safe to assume that Philippines and Japan will always keep +08 and +09 during the lifecycle of your product.

Comment: Did it changed before?

Comment: DST introduced and reverted years 1936-1937, 1954, 1978, 1990. recently proposed but not enforced 2006, 2014, last "March to June 2015 to prepare for the power crisis in the country but the President did not implement the DST"

Comment: Last time I used [_get_timezone()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/get-timezone) but I think it require some locale sync and calling _tzset. You could also try [GetTimeZoneInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724421(v=vs.85).aspx) and use `TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION`'s `Bias` field

Comment: [_tzset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/tzset) has an example

Comment: Mandatory watching before you start to implement a quick fix for your timezone problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Comment: Nothing about time and time zones is ever a simple question.

Answer (score 9):

If you would rather not dig into the Windows-specific API, here is portable, and C++20-standard C++ code<sup>1</sup> to do this using [Howard Hinnant's timezone library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html).

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using date::operator<<;
    using std::chrono::system_clock;
    std::cout << date::current_zone()->get_info(system_clock::now()).offset << '\n';
}
```

[`date::current_zone()`](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#database) detects the computer's current local time zone.  This returns a pointer to a `date::time_zone` which has a member function called `get_info()`.

You can call [`time_zone::get_info`](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#time_zone) with either a UTC `time_point` or a `local_time` `time_point` to get all kinds of information about this time zone at the indicated point in time (as the information changes with times according to current politics).  Use of `system_clock::now()` as the `time_point` will get the current information for the `time_zone`.

A [`date::sys_info`](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#sys_info) is returned which is an aggregate, one of which members is called `offset`.  This is the current UTC offset with units of `std::chrono::seconds`.

This just output for me:

```
-14400s
```

Indicating that my current local time zone is 14400 seconds west of UTC.

For typical code, one should not program down at the level of adding UTC offsets directly.  There is a higher-level API to do this for you.  Use of the higher-level API prevents careless errors such as adding the UTC offset when you should have subtracted (or vice-versa).  However this low-level API exists because sometimes low-level access to information like this is what makes your program efficient.

For example, here is a higher-level code that simply prints out the current local time:

```
std::cout << date::make_zoned(date::current_zone(), system_clock::now()) << '\n';
```

`system_clock::now()` is still explicitly called, but now the UTC offset addition, as well as the call to `current_zone()->get_info()` is encapsulated under this higher-level API.

---

<sup>1</sup> This library is in `namespace std::chrono` in C++20: http://eel.is/c++draft/time.zone.db.access#8

Answer (score 0):

If in your os, `std::localtime` can access time zone info (in most cases it can, by definition), this is my one-line code:

```
auto offset_epoch = std::localtime(new time_t(0));
```

where `offset_epoch->tm_hour` is the offset hour and `offset_epoch->tm_min` is the offset minute. You can safely ignore `offset_epoch->tm_year` as it is of value `70`.

It works fine for me so far.

Comment: I have two concerns. First, using `new time_t(0)` as a parameter to `localtime()` introduces a memory leak. It would be better to initialize a local variable of type `time_t` to `0` and pass a pointer to that variable as the parameter to `localtime()`. Second, and more importantly, the daylight savings setting in effect at the epoch might not be equal to the daylight savings setting currently in effect. Put simply, I don't think your solution takes daylight savings into account.