# How to modify time zone's time difference value in Windows 10

Tags: windows, timezone, registry, timezone-offset, regedit

My question might be look like a Superuser question but I want to write a script or code which one modifies a time zone's time difference value ie from +2 to +3 bec. of Windows 10 computers cannot update themselves automatically. I have to install cumulative update which one larger than 1GB.

I need to modify current time zone's (Istanbul) time different value from UTC +2 to UTC +3. That's it. As a workaround we are using Moscow UTC +3.

There is no standalone update to make Istanbul UTC +3 so I am asking here where can I modify a time zone in Windows 10? There are also Windows XP boxes and imho Microsoft won't publish updates for them.

Comment: I've just found the Registry location of timezones but I have no info about their details:   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones

Comment: Maybe you can get some help from http://stackoverflow.com/a/4036697/5987

Comment: 1) This is indeed a superuser question.  2) There is indeed [an update for Turkey](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dst2007/2016/10/18/time-data-update-for-turkey-is-now-available-for-windows-8-1-and-below/)  On Windows 10, you simply update to the latest build (LCU).  3) On Windows XP, you're on your own because [Windows XP is far past end of life](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/end-of-xp-support).

Comment: Also, it sounds like you've done no research, since you say in comments "I have no info about their details".  [Here's a good start](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2007/06/07/exploring-windows-time-zones-with-system-timezoneinfo-josh-free/).  You'll also find stuff [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms725481.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms724253.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I've compared old registry data and the newer one. The only changes are under
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\Turkey Standart Time:

- Display Name > From Istanbul +2 to Istanbul +3 and it has no effect.
- TZI > This is the place I've been looking for. The data is binary.

Then I've found a utility called Windows Time Zone Editor.

[image]

[image]

I could also export timezone registry from updated Windows and import it at other machines just clicking the .reg file. It works on both XP and Win 10 (WinXP.reg and Win10.reg of course).

At the moment I don't need to code anything. I hope this information can help others in the future.